# Is it possible to using web api and open a local folder?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

is it possible to click on a button on google chrome and open a folder on window or a finder on a mac using some web API, javascript or etc?

I read that some browser don't allow it due to security reason.

Comment: Programmatically, no, there isn't, unless you have an installed app having such access.

Comment: @LGSon thanks for the answer. So i need to make a desktop app instead of a web app to do this.

Comment: Simply put, yes. Based on what you actually want to do, have a look at ["progressive web apps"](https://www.google.com/search?q=progressive+web+apps&oq=progressive+web+apps+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4305j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). They are in a way installed, and can get more user rights than a normal web app, still, made out of html/css/scripts.

Comment: The dupe link has some options, limited though, but still, they might be useful.